# Transfer app from one Facebook developer account to another Facebook developer account

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

In my iOS app, it have the feature of Facebook login and other Facebook sharing feature. So to do that I created my app on the https://developers.facebook.com under my own Facebook account. But now my client wants to transfer that app to his account. So I just want to ask if is there any process through which I can transfer that app from my Facebook developer account to my client's Facebook developer account. If there is anything related to that please let me know about it in detail.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add him as admin and then remove yourself

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is a life saver for me. +1 for this.

Comment: Exactly that I was lookin for +1

Comment: do I have to add another key hashes for the new admin user ?